# React: Binding array to dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Lets say I have a class with a state level array

```
ElementsClass = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
          elements: []
      }
    },
    addElement: function() {
        var element = {
            name: ""
        };
    },
    render() {
        return (
            {this.state.elements.map(function (element, i) {
                    return <input value={element.name} />
                }
            )}
        )
}
```

The idea being that I can dynamically add to the elements array and have a new input field appearing.

How do I bind the data so that I am able to change the value in the input field and have that reflect automatically in the correct element in the elements array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically sync your inputs with your state array you can use someting called `linkState` from the [react-catalyst](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-catalyst) package. Once you've installed it with npm you can use it in the following way:

```
 //need to import
import Catalyst from 'react-catalyst'; 

ElementsClass = React.createClass({
    // mixin the linkedstate component
    mixins : [Catalyst.LinkedStateMixin],       

    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
          elements: []
      }
    },
    addElement: function() {
        var element = {
            name: ""
        };

        //add to elements array
        this.state.elements.push(element);

        //let react know to rerender necessary parts
        this.setState({
            elements : this.state.elements
        });
    },
    render() {
        return (
            {this.state.elements.map(function (element, i) {
                    //use the linkState method
                    return <input valueLink={this.linkState('elements.'+i+'.name')} />
                }
            )}
        )
}
```

The reason we need the `react-catalyst` package is that natively React's `valueLink` will only link top level state items, in your case `elements`. Obviously this isn't particularily useful but thankfully it's a fairly easy problem to solve.

**Note**: for iterated items like your element inputs, you need to provide a unique key. Something like the following (might need modifying to be more specific):

```
{this.state.elements.map(function (element, i) {
        //use the linkState method
        return <input valueLink={this.linkState('elements.'+i+'.name')} key={'elinput' + i} />
    }
)}
```

This doesn't have any outward effect on your app, it's mostly to help react target the element internally.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I clarified the question fully. When adding the `value={element.name}` to the input field, the input field cannot be modified. How can I add an onChange method that correctly targets the relevant entry in the elements array

Comment: @Pram ah, I completely misunderstood. That is actually a bit more tricky. You have to use `valueLink` instead of `value` *but* React only allows that for top level state values. I'll update my answer, but you'll need a a library like `react-catalyst` to do the two way binding that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with just ES5 and React, one solution would be this:

```
var ElementsClass = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
  return {
      elements: []
  }
},
createElement: function(){
  var element = {
    name: ''
  };
  this.setState({elements: this.state.elements.concat(element)});
},
updateElement: function(pos, event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    var updatedElements = this.state.elements.map(function(element, i){
      if (i === pos){
        return {name: value};
      }
      return element;
    });
    this.setState({elements: updatedElements});
},
render: function() {
    console.log(this.state.elements);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.elements.map(function (element, i) {
           var boundClick = this.updateElement.bind(this, i);
           return <input key={i} onKeyUp={boundClick}/>
        }.bind(this))}
        <button onClick={this.createElement}>Add Element</button>
      </div>
    )
}
});

React.render(<ElementsClass />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

You want to treat component state as immutable, so you don't want to call a mutating method like push on elements.

Comment: This answer some how saves my life! thank you

Answer (score 0):

These situations are handled easily with custom links packages.

[State and Forms in React, Part 3: Handling the Complex State](https://medium.com/@gaperton/state-and-forms-in-react-part-3-handling-the-complex-state-acf369244d37#.ok6o994zj)

```
import Link from 'valuelink';

// linked inputs will be deprecated, thus we need to use custom wrappers 
import { Input } from 'valueLink/tags.jsx'

const ElementsClass = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
          elements: []
      }
    },

    render() {
        // Take link to the element
        const elementsLink = Link.state( this, 'elements' );

        return (
            <div>
                { elementsLink.map( ( elementLink, i ) => (
                     <Input key={ i } valueLink={ elementLink.at( 'name' ) } />  
                ))}

                <button onClick={ elementsLink.push({ name : '' })}>
                    Add Elements
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```